# DCount query function in an MS-Access 2013

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I have created a Query in Access 2013, which is using two tables (tblHoliday and tblTimeTable), in order to check if the registered time is falling on a holiday. If yes, then the registered amount of hours shall be multiplied with two. I am using following Query command:

`TestHoliday: IIf(DCount("*";"tblHoliday";"[HolidayDate] between #" & (Format([StartDate];"yyyy/mm/dd")) & "# And #" & (Format([EndDate];"yyyy/mm/dd")) & "# ")>0;[InHours]*2;0)`

In sql, it looks like this:

`SELECT tblTimeTable.TimeID, tblTimeTable.EmpID, tblTimeTable.StartDate, tblTimeTable.EndDate, DateDiff("n",[StartDate],[EndDate])/60 AS InHours, IIf(DCount("*","tblHoliday","[HolidayDate] between #" & (Format([StartDate],"yyyy\/mm\/dd")) & "# And #" & (Format([EndDate],"yyyy\/mm\/dd")) & "# ")>0,[InHours]*2,0) AS TestHoliday
FROM tblTimeTable;`

When I choose Run! the Query, it all works fine, but when I choose to sort the table (i.e. from newest to oldest), or make another Query based on this Query, I get the following error message:

***Syntax error in date in query expression '[HolidayDate] = #'***.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Add an `ORDER BY` clause to your initial query ?

Comment: What is the SQL code when you filter it?

Comment: I notice the sql does not have tblHoliday in the from clause.

Comment: It is not important to order to colums, but for me this is just another indication that something is wrong with the function. Can you please explain how I can filter the SQL code in MS-Access? Do you want to add the tblHoliday in the Query and create a relation?

Comment: No updates from anybody related to this topic?